# NoSuchMethodErro r: Class 'String' has no instance method 'forEach'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
if (json['selected_shop_type'] != null) {
      final v = json['selected_shop_type'];
      final arr0 = <String>[];
      v.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(v.toString());
      });
      _selectedShopType = arr0;
    }
```

Unable to convert the Jason into dart as it giving
Error:
NoSuchMethodError : Class 'String' has no instance method 'forEach'.
Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (dynamic) => Null)

Comment: Seems like `json['selected_shop_type']` is a `String` type data and not a List/Map. And you can't use `forEach` method on String.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your json data? So that we can look into this and could tell you whether and how to convert into List and then you will be able to use the function forEach onto this.